# Conexión remota ssh para realizar mount

Tags: bash, script, ssh

Quiero establecer una conexión ssh y montar un dispositivo en un host remoto. Algo así:

```
ssh $ip 'mount $dev $dir'
```

Siendo $dev el dispositivo remoto, $dir el directorio remoto

Esto es posible?

Comment: Pues... si estableces la conexión ssh correctamente, puedes ejecutar todo lo que el usuario tenga permiso de hacer. La pregunta es: ¿qué pasó cuando intentaste usar tu código? Encontraste algún error?

Comment: Tal vez quiere rsh?

Comment: ¿No quisiste preguntar "Cómo montar un dispositivo local a un host remoto"? Si es así, puedes utilizar sshfs.